# Displaying Django form answers

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I couldn't find a solution to this on the Django website, currently I have a form as shown:

It saves to my models.py like the following:

What I want to do is use the answers from a form and create a new form using the answers of this form as the questions for it, basically recreating this form and reusing the fields but changing the fields and displaying it on a unique URL

```
class InitialForm(forms.Form):
    Teacher_Name = forms.CharField(label='Teacher Name')
    Test_Name = forms.CharField(label='Label this test')
    Subject = forms.CharField(label = 'Subject')
    Question = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the first question?')
    Topic = forms.CharField(label = 'What topic is this on?')
    Option1 = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the first option?')
    Option2 = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the second option?')
    Option3 = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the third option?')
    Option4 = forms.CharField(label = 'What is the fourth option?')
    Answer = forms.CharField(label = 'Which option is the correct option?', widget=forms.Select(choices=Options))

class Questions(models.Model):
    testID = AutoSlugField(unique=True)
    test_label = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    teacherName = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null = True)
    studentID = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Q1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null = True)
    Topic1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option1_Q1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option2_Q1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option3_Q1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Option4_Q1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    AnswerQ1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    ``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to step back and think about what objects you are going to store in your database amd what you do with them, and most importantly, how they are related. Getting the relationships right as early as possible is the most important thing, because it's hardest to change later.

I would guess that there's something like a `Test` which has `Question`s, and that each `Student` will be sumbitting `Answer`s to the `Test`.

`Question` objects will have a ForeignKey relationship to a `Test`. `Answer` objects will have a `ForeignKey` relationship both to a `Test` and to a `Student`.

You now have a whole set of views to write. There will be `CreateView` and `UpdateView` (and probably `DeleteView`) that an (authenticated!) teacher will use to manipulate the `Question` objects for a particular `Test`. The text of the `Question` and the option details will be displayed to each Student sitting the test; the student will respond with  his choice for the right answer which will be recorded as an `Answer` object`

The student-answer form will input just one field: the student's chosen answer (A to D, or 1 to 4?) What the student sees will be a display of a `Question` object: a read-only view of the Question data which was input by the teacher.

Chances are that after you get the hang of this you will be introducing `Teacher` and `Course` objects (multiple `Test` objects linked to one `Course`. one or more `Teacher` objects linked to one `Course`, ...)

Opinionated, but this is exactly the sort of problem that Class-Based Views make easy, so use them.

Comment: Thank you, I will work using your advice, I am pretty new to doing things like this, still learning coding in general <3